# Connecting STM32F103C through USB as well as external power supply

Tags: usb

What will happen if I connect a STM32F103C board to a USB as well as an external power supply? Will it work? Does the STM32 decide which power source to consider?

Comment: At least I know, you never should connect USB and the SWD VCC pin simultaneously. Do you have a datasheet/picture of your model? Since I cannot recall any STM32F103 board with external power supply (except normal supply via USB or SWD).

Comment: I don't have a picture of the model. With arduino boards you can have external and USB supply simultaneously. I'm using stm board now, so I just wanted to make sure if it's possible or not before I end up doing somthing I'll regret later on.

Comment: Without a link/datasheet I don't think anyone can answer. A picture is the least important, a link (on internet) or datasheet would help more. Arduino boards normally have an external power supplies, STM32 boards don't (unless shown otherwise).

Comment: you can test to see if there's a diode between the usb's 5 volt line and the devkit's 5V pin. If there is, you should be fine. If not, it will probably smoke something.